# (PETSc4py) Creating Distributed Sparse Block Matrix with `createAIJWithArrays'

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, petsc

I am trying to create a sparse block matrix in PETSc4py using local matrices assembled with SciPy. Below is a simple example code with comments

```
import numpy as np
import petsc4py
from petsc4py import PETSc
import scipy.sparse as sp

def main():
    # Initialize parallel PETSc4py
    petsc4py.init()
    
    comm = PETSc.COMM_WORLD
    
    comm_rank = comm.getRank()
    comm_size = comm.getSize()
    
    # Create local matrices
    n = 4
    n_local = n
    n_global = int(comm_size * n)
    
    A_local = sp.random(n_local, n_local, density = 0.5, format = 'csr') \
        + sp.identity(n)
    A_local = (A_local + A_local.transpose()) / 2.

    # Get CSRSpec for createAIJWithArrays
    [II, JJ, VV] = sp.find(A_local)
    [_, II] = np.unique(II, return_index = True)
    II = np.array(np.append(II, len(II) - 1), dtype = np.int32)
    
    # Create PETSc sparse matrix
    A = PETSc.Mat()
    A.createAIJWithArrays(size = [n_global, n_global], csr = [II, JJ, VV],
                          bsize = [n_local, n_local], comm = comm)
    
    # Communicate off-rank values and setup internal data structures for
    # performing parallel operations
    A.assemblyBegin()
    A.assemblyEnd()
    
    PETSc.Sys.Print(A)

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code works properly when running a single process, but when running with two processes it returns the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/jltor/Education and Research/misc/PETSc4py/matmpibaij/main.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/jltor/Education and Research/misc/PETSc4py/matmpibaij/main.py", line 31, in main
    A.createAIJWithArrays(size = [n_global, n_global], csr = [II, JJ, VV],
  File "petsc4py/PETSc/Mat.pyx", line 449, in petsc4py.PETSc.Mat.createAIJWithArrays
petsc4py.PETSc.Error: error code 55
[0] MatCreateMPIAIJWithArrays() at /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/petsc_1688117131282/work/src/mat/impls/aij/mpi/mpiaij.c:4216
[0] MatMPIAIJSetPreallocationCSR() at /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/petsc_1688117131282/work/src/mat/impls/aij/mpi/mpiaij.c:4013
[0] MatMPIAIJSetPreallocationCSR_MPIAIJ() at /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/petsc_1688117131282/work/src/mat/impls/aij/mpi/mpiaij.c:3936
[0] MatMPIAIJSetPreallocation() at /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/petsc_1688117131282/work/src/mat/impls/aij/mpi/mpiaij.c:4148
[0] MatMPIAIJSetPreallocation_MPIAIJ() at /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/petsc_1688117131282/work/src/mat/impls/aij/mpi/mpiaij.c:2946
[0] MatSeqAIJSetPreallocation() at /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/petsc_1688117131282/work/src/mat/impls/aij/seq/aij.c:3949
[0] MatSeqAIJSetPreallocation_SeqAIJ() at /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/petsc_1688117131282/work/src/mat/impls/aij/seq/aij.c:4015
[0] PetscMallocA() at /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/petsc_1688117131282/work/src/sys/memory/mal.c:411
[0] PetscMallocAlign() at /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/petsc_1688117131282/work/src/sys/memory/mal.c:53
[0] Out of memory. Allocated: 0, Used by process: 80764928
[0] Memory requested 18446744073709551616
[1]PETSC ERROR: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1]PETSC ERROR: Caught signal number 11 SEGV: Segmentation Violation, probably memory access out of range
[1]PETSC ERROR: Try option -start_in_debugger or -on_error_attach_debugger
[1]PETSC ERROR: or see https://petsc.org/release/faq/#valgrind and https://petsc.org/release/faq/
[1]PETSC ERROR: configure using --with-debugging=yes, recompile, link, and run
[1]PETSC ERROR: to get more information on the crash.
[1]PETSC ERROR: Run with -malloc_debug to check if memory corruption is causing the crash.
```

Error Code 55 seems to correspond to an [inability to allocate requested memory](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-3.9/include/petscerror.h.html).

**Why is so much memory being requested, and what do I need to change to this example code to fix this?**

I have tried running this code with different numbers of processes and different size block matrices, which yielded the same result (including the same amount of memory requested). I also have looked into PETSc4py Error Code 55, which seemed to only return a result on repeatedly setting up a KSP object.

Comment: often  memory errors with sparse, something is trying create full dense arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj Understood! I wouldn't expect a memory error when trying to create an 8X8 array of floats, though (n = 4). The error also appears for n = 3.